# Selected value is not display in admin edit form

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]I have created below option in admin edit form. It is showing selected value in grid but in edit, it is displaying default value like only first option.

[image]
For ex. Smartphone is "Device Type" in grid, But when I go to edit form it display Tablet not Smartphone.

Code used in `Grid.php`

```
static public function getOptionArray4()
{
    $data_array=array(); 
    $data_array[0]='';
    $data_array[1]='Tablet';
    $data_array[2]='Smartphone';
    return($data_array);
}

static public function getValueArray4()
{
    $data_array=array();
    foreach(Allin_Devices_Block_Adminhtml_Devices_Grid::getOptionArray4() as $k=>$v){
       $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
    }
    return($data_array);

}
```

and below code used in `form.php`

```
$fieldset->addField('mobile_tablet', 'select', array(
    'name'  => 'mobile_tablet',
    'label' => Mage::helper('devices')->__('Select Device Type'),
    'values'   => Allin_Devices_Block_Adminhtml_Devices_Grid::getValueArray4()
));
```

Comment: put the code of admin grid of "mobile_tablet" field

Comment: First code of Admin grid for "mobile_tablet" field

Comment: First code is only option array which used in form as well as in grid. Please send the grid field binding code (ex. $fieldset->addField('mobile_tablet',) same as in form

Comment: thanks @AshishJagnani for your reply. I have got the solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The field name should be same like in table `mobile_tablet`

And in Grid.php  **_prepareColumns()** method should be same as like below for `mobile_tablet` column.

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    .............

    $this->addColumn('mobile_tablet', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('devices')->__('Select Device Type'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'mobile_tablet',
        'type' => 'options',
        'options' => Allin_Devices_Block_Adminhtml_Devices_Grid::getOptionArray4()
    ));

    .............

}
```